# UITapGesture firing before previous one has ended

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've set up a tap gesture to complete an action like this:

```
func setupGestures() {
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}

@objc func handleSingleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        jumpUp()
    }
}

func jumpUp() {
    if let action = jumpAction {
        addBlocks()
        playerNode.runAction(action)
    }
}
```

However, I can tap multiple times and my object stays in the air (continues the jump action) as it's registering the tap gesture continuously rather than letting it finish first before another tap can be registered. How can I fix this so that a tap gesture can only happen one at a time? Other answers suggested adding the `sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended` but it hasn't worked.

Comment: If you define your `singleTap` gesture outside of your function you can disable it when the `runAction` is happening so that the gesture will not receive another tap during the run animation.`singleTap.enabled = false` . Once the `runAction` is done , probably in your completion block, you can enable it again. I think that should fix the issue.

Comment: Your problem is, you are firing the jumpAction once the gesture `state == ended` which is fine but while the animation is taking a place, there is nothing that stops the gesture to receive another tap! That's what I was trying to explain above..

Comment: @lionserdar thank you! adding `sender.isEnabled = false` while firing and then `sender.isEnabled = true` in the completion handler worked. I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by passing `sender` as an argument to the `jumpUp()` function and adding `sender.isEnabled = true` in its the completion handler:

```
@objc func handleSingleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            sender.isEnabled = false
            jumpUp(sender)
    }

func jumpUp(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let action = jumpAction {
            addBlocks()
            playerNode.runAction(action, completionHandler: {
                sender.isEnabled = true
            })
        }
    }
```